# Clerk.js make multiple pages public

Tags: javascript, regex, authentication, public, clerk

I'm using Clerk.JS (in Next.JS). I have some code that looks like:

```js
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/"]
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

I want to also have a public route on an arbitrary url, such as `example.com/test/abc123`. However, clerk.js doesn't seem to allow `publicRoutes: ['test/*']`. What's the best solution to this?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

###EDIT###

Solution: "/test/(.*)

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
    export default authMiddleware({
        publicRoutes: ["/", 'test/:id']
    });
```